# prometheus is not available in actuator endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, prometheus, grafana, spring-boot-actuator

I've tried to configure prometheus for metrics in grafana,
`<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId> </dependency> (spring boot version: 3.1.0)`

`management: endpoint: shutdown: enabled: true endpoints: web: exposure: include: "*" metrics: distribution: percentiles-histogram: "[http.server.requests]": true prometheus: metrics: export: enabled: true pushgateway: enabled: true`
app.yml

`global:
scrape_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:

- job_name: 'spring-actuator'
  metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
  static_configs:

  - targets: ['localhost:8080']`
    prometheus yml

`volumes:
minio-data:
driver: local

services:
minio:
image: minio/minio:latest
container_name: minio
environment:
- MINIO_ROOT_USER=minioadmin
- MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=minioadmin
command: server ~/minio --console-address :9091
ports:
- '9091:9091'
- '9000:9000'
volumes:
- minio-data:/minio
prometheus:
image: prom/prometheus
ports:
- 9090:9090
volumes:
- ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
command:
- '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'

```
grafana:
  image: grafana/grafana
  ports:
    - 3000:3000
  environment:
    - GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
  volumes:
    - ./grafana:/var/lib/grafana`
```

`docker compose yaml`

Tried to configure prometheus and enable /actuator/prometheus endpoint, but all tries were unsuccessful. though grafana and prometheus are enable on their hosts.